# @ControllerAdvice in Exception handling

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have used the validation in my project to handle the exceptions but now I know @ ControllerAdvice is also used for exception handling can anyone tell me why I use it and what the difference is and how to use it, as I am not able to understand from the resources.

**Using validation :**

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    @Validated
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        UserRepository userrepo;
        
        @PostMapping(value="/users")
        ResponseEntity<?> create( @Valid @RequestBody User user) {
            
            User addeduser = userrepo.save(user);
            URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                                .path("/{id}")
                                .buildAndExpand(addeduser.getId())
                                .toUri();
            
            return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
        }
```

**Using ControllerAdvice:**

```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalResponseException {
        @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
        public void handleMyException() {}
    }
```

Want I really want to know is how it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ControllerAdvice is a specialization of the @Component annotation which allows to handle exceptions across the whole application in one global handling component. It can be viewed as an interceptor of exceptions thrown by methods annotated with @RequestMapping and similar.
you can also refer this:
https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f

Comment: i dont want definition i want to know how it is working

Comment: i am posting this question from the resources what i really want to know how exactly it is working

Comment: how controller Advice will connect with controller and throw exception

Comment: thankyou for your reference it explains everything.

Comment: so if my reference works for you please give me a tick I need one